# Maximum area of a triangle when two sides are given

Tags: calculus

Two sides of a triangle are 2 cm and 3 cm . What can be the maximum area of the triangle ?

Comment: you know more things for example which is the angle between the 2 sides to solve the triangle

Comment: @JoseGarcia:  It makes sense, if you wish to look at it in those terms, to ask what angle would maximize the area.

Comment: Well didn't see it was tagged under calculus. I used Euclidean geometry.

Comment: @Gopesh:  It is hard for Readers to guess what about this exercise gave you difficulty.  Please add some context, e.g. what you tried, what makes the problem interesting to you, or what results and worked examples you believe are related to the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\alpha$ is the angle between the edges that have $2$ and $3$ lengths. Since area of triangle can be found with:

> $$\frac{1}{2}\sin(\alpha)a\cdot b$$

So let $A(\alpha)$ is a function that giving us the area of triangle. $$A(\alpha)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(\alpha)\cdot2\cdot3$$
We can find the maximum value of this function by taking it's derivative:
$$A^{'}(\alpha)=3\cos(\alpha)=0 \\
\cos(\alpha)=0 \\
\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
So when the angle between these two lines is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ triangle will have maximum area. Let's calculate it:
$$A(\frac{\pi}{2})=\frac{1}{2}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})\cdot2\cdot3=$$
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
3
$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $2$ as **base** of triangle. Then area is given by

$$A =\frac{1}{2}\text{ base} \times \text{height}$$ Now to maximise area, **height** must be maximum. So height must be $3$.

So third side is $\sqrt{2^2+3^2} = \sqrt{13}$.

Maximum area is $$A_{max}=\frac{1}{2}\ (2\times 3) = 3\text{ cm}^2$$

Comment: @Arby No sir, that would be only $\sqrt{8}$ ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess when the two sides are at a right angle to each other. This would result in the largest height for a side meaning it'd get the most area.

Answer (score 0):

The area of a triangle is base × height divided by 2. Fix one side as the base, and rotate the other side...
The height of the triangle(and thus the area) is maximum When the other side is at 90 degrees from the first, in which case you have a right triangle with an area equal to half the product of the two starting sides.

So, Maximum area is given as, 
$$    
A=\frac{1}{2}\ (2\times 3) = 3\text{ cm}^2
$$